# Setting a column style? (Unmanaged c++)

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, unmanaged

I'm currently able to set a listview style VIA the ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle method, however this makes all columns have the same style. My goal is to only modify one column (to basically have the LVS_EX_UNDERLINEHOT|LVS_EX_UNDERLINECOLD|LVS_EX_TWOCLICKACTIVATE style).

Is there a way to modify the style of only one column and not the entire table?

Edit: Or even a way to custom draw the cell?

Comment: Please never use the phrase 'unmanaged c++'. That phrase is used by language bigots to imply that C++ is inferior to their 'managed' environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [WTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/) framework then there is a very useful CCustomDraw class that you can use to easily intercept NM_CUSTOMDRAW messages and draw your own listview content.

There is a good CodeProject article on custom draw using WTL [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/customdrawlist_wtl.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There is a tutorial on Using ListView control under Win32 API, on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/listview.aspx).

Look for the part called **---Sub item Colors---** under **"ListView Colors"**.
There you will see the following code, in which you should put your corresponding  ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle() call inside the case statement:

```
case CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: 
        {
            switch(lplvcd->iSubItem)
            {
                case 0: // Your first column
```